# 'Unnamed 0' Pandas при конвертировании Excel в CSV

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, excel, csv

У меня есть [вот такая таблица](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXld5.png) в формате .xls. Используя функцию `df.to_csv()` библиотеки *pandas* я получаю [следующее](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzhHd.png) но уже в формате CSV. Суть вопроса: изначально в моей таблице есть пустая клетка, которая записывается в DataFrame как 'Unnamed 0', мне нужно как-то избавиться от подобного без редактирования исходников и удаления столбцов

Comment: Эту искусственно созданную проблему надо решать на этапе создания .XLS файла. Если делать это позже то вам приходится чинить уже поломанную таблицу. Чтобы починить код для создания .XLS, достаточно сделать так: df.reset_index().to_excel(filename, index=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Замечание:*

Я предлагаю вам решение вашего вопроса так, как я его понял. Когда вы хотите что-то другое, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, уточняя, что вы хотите.

(Не имеет смысла уточнят непонятно заданный вопрос в  форме комментарий.)

---

```
# Переименование первого столбца
correct_name  = df.iloc[0,0]
bad_name = df.columns[0]
df_result = df.rename({bad_name: correct_name}, axis=1)

# Сдвиг первого столбца и дополнение следующим значением
first_col = df.iloc[:,0]
last_val  = first_col.iloc[-1]
first_col = first_col.shift(-1, fill_value=last_val+1)

# Замена сдвинутым и дополненным столбцом
df_result[correct_name] = first_col
```

---

Оригинальный датафрейм (`df`):

> ```
>    Unnamed: 0  testl  test2  test3
> 0        Time  44.79    1.7   1.70
> 1           0  44.86    1.7   1.71
> 2           1  44.92    1.7   1.71
> 3           2  44.97    1.7   1.71
> 4           3  45.04    1.7   1.71
> 5           4  45.10    1.7   1.71
> 6           5  45.16    1.7   1.71
> 7           6  45.21    1.7   1.71
> 8           7  45.26    1.7   1.71
> 9           8  45.31    1.7   1.71
> 10          9  45.35    1.7   1.71
> 11         10  45.39    1.7   1.71
> 12         11  45.42    1.7   1.71
> ```

Результат (`df_result`):

```
   Time  testl  test2  test3
0     0  44.79    1.7   1.70
1     1  44.86    1.7   1.71
2     2  44.92    1.7   1.71
3     3  44.97    1.7   1.71
4     4  45.04    1.7   1.71
5     5  45.10    1.7   1.71
6     6  45.16    1.7   1.71
7     7  45.21    1.7   1.71
8     8  45.26    1.7   1.71
9     9  45.31    1.7   1.71
10   10  45.35    1.7   1.71
11   11  45.39    1.7   1.71
12   12  45.42    1.7   1.71
```