# Pandas конкатенация DataFrame

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, excel

Не подскажите как из вот из этой таблицы

[image: этой таблицы]

и из этой

[image: этой]

получить вот это:

[image: вот это]

Пробовал использовать `pd.concat(df1, df2)` и вот это получалось:

[image: вот что]

(лишняя строка Time-test1-test2-test3)

Comment: приведите примеры данных в виде текста / CSV файлов или выложите файлы на какой-нибудь файлообменник. Врядли здесь найдутся энтузиасты готовые набивать данные из картинок для того, чтобы вам помочь...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и в вашем [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1170137/211923), ваша главная проблема, по-моему, в недопонимании базовых принципов того, как работает Pandas и что из себя представляет `Pandas.DataFrame`.

Таблица в Pandas (объект типа: `Pandas.DataFrame`) это типизированный набор именованых столбцов (объект типа: `Pandas.Series`).

Пример:

```
In [95]: df = pd.DataFrame({"int_col": [1, 2, 3], "float_col":[3.1415, 2.7183, 0], "str_col":["aa", "bb", "cc"]})

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   int_col  float_col str_col
0        1     3.1415      aa
1        2     2.7183      bb
2        3     0.0000      cc

In [97]: df.dtypes
Out[97]:
int_col        int64
float_col    float64
str_col       object
dtype: object
```

Каждый столбец имеет имя и тип данных. Мы можем легко выполнять арифметические операции над числовыми столбцами:

```
In [99]: df["int_col"].sum()
Out[99]: 6
```

Теперь давайте посмотрим что произойдет если присвоить **одной ячейке** числового столбца *строковое* значение:

```
In [103]: df.loc[0, "int_col"] = "Time"

In [104]: df
Out[104]:
  int_col  float_col str_col
0    Time     3.1415      aa
1       2     2.7183      bb
2       3     0.0000      cc

In [105]: df.dtypes
Out[105]:
int_col       object  # <------ тип столбца поменялся с `int64` на `object` (строка)
float_col    float64
str_col       object
dtype: object
```

теперь мы не можем выполнять арифметические операции над этим столбцом:

```
In [106]: df["int_col"].sum()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...<skipped>...
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

**NOTE:** Таким образом изменив всего одну ячейку на строку в числовом столбце, мы потеряли возможность выполнять арифметические операции над всем столбцом. Эта проблема решается при помощи уродливых "костылей", но не проще ли изначально не создавать себе таких проблем??

---

## Вывод:

Проблемы вы себе создали на более ранних этапах, когда неправильно читали/сохраняли данные из/в  CSV / Excel / HTML / etc. файлов в Pandas DataFrame.

Исправлять такие ошибки **гораздо сложнее и затратнее** по сравнению с тем, чтобы изначально правильно прочитать данные.

Поэтому правильным подходом в вашем случае будет правильное чтение / парсинг данных на более ранних этапах, тогда и `pd.concat([df1, df2])` будет правильно работать и типы данных не испортятся (не будут превращаться в `object`) и арифметические операции будут работать и т.д. и т.п.